# What should be the type of function which returns array of Promises

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, types

I have a function, which basically returns array of Promises. What should be the return type of the function? Below is the code

```
const makeLabelNodesRequest: Promise<K8sResourceKind> = (selectedNode: NodeKind[]) => {
const labelPath = '/metadata/labels';
const labelData = selectedNode.map((node: NodeKind) => {
  const labels = SelectorInput.arrayify(_.get(node, labelPath.split('/').slice(1)));
  const lblVal = { ...SelectorInput.objectify(labels), ...labelObj };
  const patch = [
    {
      op: labels.length ? 'replace' : 'add',
      value: lblVal,
      path: labelPath,
    },
  ];
  return k8sPatch(NodeModel, node, patch); // returns a promise
});
return labelData; //array of Promise
```

};

Its giving this error - [ts] Type '(selectedNode: NodeKind[]) => Promise[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Promise': then, catch, [Symbol.toStringTag].
Please note NodeKind and K8sResourceKind are custom types.

Comment: `Array<Promise<K8sResourceKind>>`?

Comment: Looks like k8sPatch function's return type is not a Promise

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 options :

```
const makeLabelNodesRequest: Array<Promise<K8sResourceKind>>
```

Or

```
const makeLabelNodesRequest: Promise<K8sResourceKind>[]
```

The first solution is just an alias of the second one, which should be indicated by your IDE autocompletion.

None of these solutions have an advantage other the other, just stay consistent and use a single syntax in your codebase.